# Problems sorting tables by clicking header

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon.

I have the task of ordering the columns by clicking on header, order asc and desc. I was investigating, I made these headers, I brought a function but I can't get it to enter. I made an alert to test but it never manages to open.

I have everything in an html, I put it inside the script because that's how they were already using it, I can't change it.

the problem is that the onclick of the sortable is not responding

```html
  <script id="rowTicket" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

        <table border="1" id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Destacados</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Nombre</th>
                    <th>Organización</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Número</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="wc_ticket_table_<%=tr_i%>" class="" data-index="<%=tr_i%>"                      data-id="<%= newObj.id %>">


                    <td class="wc-check" width="32px">
                        <span class="ico ico-checkbox-unchecked2"></span>
                        <span class="ico ico-checkbox-checked"></span>
                    </td>


                    <td class="wc-star" width="32px">
                        <%
                        var star = '';
                        if ( newObj.important ) {
                        star = '<span class="ico ico-star6"></span>'
                        } else {
                        star = '<span class="ico ico-star4"></span>'
                        }
                        %>

                        <%= star %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= newObj.id %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="wc-name-td">
                        <p>
                            <a href="javascript:;" title="<%= newObj.name %>">
                                <%= newObj.name %>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        <%
                        var activClass = ''; agentClass = '';
                        if ( gShowOwner) {
                        activClass = 'wc-hidden'; agentClass = '';
                        } else {
                        activClass = ''; agentClass = 'wc-hidden';
                        }
                        %>
                        <small class="wc-agentname <%= agentClass %>"><span                               class=""><%= newObj.nameAgent %></span></small>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p><span class="ico ico-office"></span> <span                                     class="name"><%= newObj.company %></span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="wc-phone-td">
                        <p class="wc-mail-in"><span class="ico ico-envelop">                               </span> <span class="name"><%= newObj.email %></span></p>
                    </td>

                    <td class="wc-phone-td">
                        <p class="wc-phone-in"><span class="ico ico-phone"></span>                          <span class="name"><%= newObj.phone %></span></p>
                    </td>

                    <td class="wc-phone-td wc-hidden">
                        <small class="wc-activity"><span title="Última actividad                            <%= dateFormatTitle%>" class=""><%= dateFormat %></span>                        </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class="wc-sentiment-td wc-hidden">
                        <p>
                            <%= newObj.sentiment %>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>

    </script>

    <script>
        function sortTable(n) {
            alert("hello");
            var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount =             0;
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            switching = true;
            dir = "asc";
            
            while (switching) {
                switching = false;
                rows = table.rows;
                for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                    
                    shouldSwitch = false;
                    
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
                    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
                    
                    if (dir == "asc") {
                        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                          
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (dir == "desc") {
                        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                           
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                  
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                    switching = true;
                    
                    switchcount++;
                } else {
                   
                    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                        dir = "desc";
                        switching = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide [minimal reproducable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It is easier to help you debug that way.

Comment: I tested the code and it runs. So not sure what your problem is. Seems odd you are sorting the 1 when it is the 4th column in the table.

Comment: @epascarello did it work for you? When I click on the header, which I have marked as (1), it's just a test, it doesn't enter the function I have below... that's why it doesn't order correctly. I thought it was because of the script